# Looking for a book title about a stolen battleship

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book a number of years ago but can't find it or remember the title (I thought it was Iron Giant - but don't think that's the case). Criminals have stolen a WW2 battleship (I want to say that it was based on the Yamato) and are causing havoc on the waves. Nothing modern can touch her, they try modern planes (modern pilots/planes not built/trained to evade flack) and ships (newer radar and missiles bounce off the hull) to sink it, so they dust off the Missouri and Idaho battleships to sink her. I think the criminal faction were stealing nukes. Google has not been my friend here.

Comment: You hint at things here that could be science fictional or fantastical but aren't necessarily; mainly with: _"Nothing modern can touch it"_. Could you [edit] this to elaborate on what makes it science fictional or fantastical? If it isn't you may want to check out [literature.se] instead.

Comment: tweaked as requested

Comment: Sounds pretty unbelievable, a handful of modern harpoon missiles could quite readily put a crimp in any WWII-era battleship

Comment: It does sound similar to "The Iron Man" by John Watson

Comment: "There are only two kinds of ships on the seas: submarines and targets."

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I think you are right on the money

Comment: @HorusKol the ship is said to have 24" thick armour plate. Would that stand up to a harpoon missile? (I genuinely don't know  ;)

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez you don't have to hit the armoured hull to knock a ship out of action - even then, harpoons deliver the same explosive power as WWII torpedoes, and they were enough to sink battleships.

Comment: Thanks all super appreciate the help, been looking for years for this. Yup totally unbelievable but a fun read (if you park reality for a little while)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds as if you are just slightly misremembering the title; instead of *Iron Giant* I believe you are thinking of *[The Iron Man](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Iron_Man.html?id=OPlxGwAACAAJ)*, a 1998 novel by John Watson (not to be confused with the [work by Ted Hughes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?621273) with the same title.)

The plot follows the theft of a Russian world War II era battleship, the "Stalin". As the OP recalled, it was designed to counter the *Yamamoto* and so has thicker armour and heavier armament than usual. In the course of the novel two F-15 attack the ship with no result, it shrugs off torpedos and missiles from the *USS Jackson* and so eventually two Iowa class battleships, the *Iowa* (not the *Idaho*) and the *Missouri* are pulled out of mothballs to sink it. The intent of the criminals was indeed to steal nuclear weapons, namely anti-submarine nuclear warheads.

If this is the book in question, then I doubt that it really fits as F&SF though.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, I've been looking for this for YEARS.... Super appreciated!